# EXC_BAD_ACCESS onTouchEnded when using Widget in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

This is my code. I have layer 1 contains button 1 and layer 2 contains button 2. I'm using the UI to load the layers and button from Cocos Studio exported files. I added touch for 2 button, and write the touchEvent function below. However, when I test, sometimes, it causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS onTouchEnded. Do you know why and how to fix this issue?

It seems similar with this issue
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/bug-ui-button-cant-delete-it-self/16282

Thank you very much

```
if (listener->onTouchEnded)
{
       listener->onTouchEnded(*touchesIter, event); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
}


void FJPopupLayer::touchEvent(Ref *pSender, ui::Widget::TouchEventType type,
                              BUTTON_TAG button) {
    switch (type) {
        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::BEGAN:
            break;

        case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::MOVED:
            break;

       case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED:
            if (button == 1) {
                // Remove the layer 2
                // Add the layer 1
            } else if (button == 2) {
              // Remove the layer 1
              // Add the layer 2
            }
            break;

       case ui::Widget::TouchEventType::CANCELED:
            break;

        default:
            break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Which of the variables has a bad value? Turn on breakpoints for exceptions and you should be able to see in the debugger.

Comment: @Jason: The bad value is the touch when it gets the touch ended event of the touch which is released. But I don't know how to fix it, and I don't know why it happens. It seems similar with this http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/bug-ui-button-cant-delete-it-self/16282

Comment: Did you test `touchesIter` and the value returned from the dereference of it?

Comment: Yes, I tested, and I tried to solutions in the link but unsuccessfully